# Handling Date Format - VB.Net/SQL Server Based WebApp

Tags: vb.net, date-format, globalization

I have a Web App and trying to make date format configurable by users as for example people in London should be able to view and enter dates in `dd/MM/yyyy` format while people in the US `MM/dd/yyyy`.

Dates are being stored in the DB in smalldatetime.  Displaying according to user preference is no issue as `String.Format` or `toString(format)` can be used according to user preference whenever a date is displayed.  The issue is when a user enters the date.  Suppose the server is in the US and uses US cultureinfo by default.  So when a date in `MM/dd/yyyy` format is entered by the user on a page, the server works fine.  But not able to figure out the best way to implement such that when user preference for date format is `dd/MM/yyyy` and when user inputs a date, the code first converts it in `MM/dd/yyyy` format through some centralized setting so that all lines where dates are handled are not required to be changed.

Comment: Dates do not have a format.  They are a value representing ticks since 12:00 midnight, January 1, 0001 C.E.  If the db column is really a date, any `MM/dd/yyyy` is just that value being displayed in a format you can understand.

Comment: You are missing my question.  If a method function includes say  _date as date and if user enters 28/3/2015, it will not work. Same when a string entered by a user needs to be converted into a VB Date object

Comment: "Dates are being stored in the DB in US format."  I certainly hope not, because that would mean that they were being stored as text. Why would you store anything that is not text as text? If you're using SQL Server then you should be using its `datetime2` or `date` data type or the like, depending on exactly what values you need to store. If that's you're doing then no, they are not being stored in US format or any other format. They are just numbers. I understand that that is not an answer to your question but I wanted to reinforce that point.

Comment: I haven't read it carefully but I wonder whether this might be of use: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20703894/how-to-detect-the-browsers-format-for-inputtype-date

Comment: No they are being stored as smalldatetime

Comment: @jmcilhinney I am looking for server side handling of this but thanks for the link.  It is quite informative.

Comment: This problem has been solved. All you had to do is google. Just store all your dates in UTC and each user should have an offset. Apply this offset for each user date to get UTC when storing and retrieving dates. Done - each user has correct date anywhere on the globe. Let user select culture and also which format they want to see dates as. Or determine where user coming from and set culture automatically. Format and culture - 2 different things. You mostly need culture.